# LINQ Lambda Improvement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a line like so:

```
var lstOfIds = db.TBL_AssocIncidentSpecialCat
                .Where(x => x.IncidentId == incidentVm.ID)
                .Select(t => t.SpecialCategoriesId)
                .ToList();
```

This line gathers me a list of of the `SpecialCategoriesId`s.  Then I have to do this:

```
incidentVm.LstSpecialCategories = db.TBL_SpecialCategories
                                    .Where(x => lstOfIds.Contains(x.Id))
                                    .Select(t => t.SpecialCategory)
                                    .ToList();
```

Is there a way to combine these two lines into one?  Even though it's only two lines of code.. I feel as though having to grab the Ids first then having to grab the associated property based on the Id is just an extra step and could be shortened to just one line.  But I may be wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
incidentVm.LstSpecialCategories = db.TBL_AssocIncidentSpecialCat
                                    .Where(x => x.IncidentId == incidentVm.ID)
                                    .Join(
                                        db.TBL_SpecialCategories, 
                                        x => new{Id = x.SpecialCategoriesId},
                                        t => new{Id = t.Id},
                                        (x,t) => {return t.SpecialCategory}
                                    );
```

I am getting red squiggly under last part in `Join`:

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: This is entity framework.  Sorry, I'll add to the tags.  Those types are domain types from Entity Framework

Comment: See https://www.tektutorialshub.com/join-query-entity-framework/ on how to do a join with EF

Comment: You could always use `Join()` with the id's.

Comment: @Kwinten anyway you could provide an example. I'm currently working on it as well

Comment: @mjwills okay, now I have red squiggly under `Join`.. **The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly**

Comment: you create new objects as the join attributes. the lambda expressions should point to value types. Try x=>x.SpecialCategoriesId etc. instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two lines using `Join`. Something like,

```
var result = db.TBL_AssocIncidentSpecialCat
                .Join(
                    db.TBL_SpecialCategories,
                    ais => new { Id = ais.IncidentId },
                    sc => new { Id = sc.Id },
                    (ais, sc) => { return sc; }
                )
                .ToList();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1WAmnE) for this.

**Update with Where Clause**: You should use your `Where` condition after the `Join`.

```
var result = db.TBL_AssocIncidentSpecialCat
                .Join(
                    db.TBL_SpecialCategories,
                    ais => new { Id = ais.IncidentId },
                    sc => new { Id = sc.Id },
                    (ais, sc) => new { ais = ais, sc = sc }
                )
                .Where(x => x.ais.IncidentId == 1)
                .Select(y => y.sc)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: @M12Bennett I have updated the answer. The `Where` clause should be after the `Join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a LINQ query-style join:

```
incidentVm.LstSpecialCategories = (from aispc in db.TBL_AssocIncidentSpecialCat
                                    join spc in db.TBL_SpecialCategories
                                    on aispc.SpecialCategoriesId equals lspc.Id
                                    where aispc.IncidentId == incidentVm.ID
                                    select lspc.SpecialCategory).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with the help of some answers and me testing it on my own.  Here is my solution:

```
incidentVm.LstSpecialCategories = db.TBL_AssocIncidentSpecialCat
                                    .Where(t => t.IncidentId == incidentVm.ID)
                                    .Join(db.TBL_SpecialCategories,
                                        ik => ik.SpecialCategoriesId,
                                        ok => ok.Id,
                                        (ik, ok) => ok.SpecialCategory
                                    )
                                    .ToList();
```

Thank you for all of your help.